# Calculate unique page views

Tags: node.js

How would I go about tracking the unique page views for a page in a NodeJS app and saving them into the DB? Something like most app like Instagram or Dribbble etc. has where they count the views of a certain page uniquely means a page refresh won't recount.

What's the best algorithm behind this?

Answer (score 2):

- A simple approach would be to count the number of records in your "sessions" table/collection.
- Another way would be to track all IPs that requests are made from, but this isn't advisable because you'll miss people behind a router.
- If you just wish to track registered users, you could:

  1. Maintain a 'lastLogin' property in the User model so you can make queries like "number of users who have visited since [datetime]"
  2. Maintain a separate collection/table that maintains sessionIds, IPs, usernames and anything else you want. This would allow you to track very flexibly at the expense of more database work. This works for both registered and unregistered users since you track everything that identifies a visit.
- You may also wish to reconsider if you want to track pageviews/sessions at all. If traction is all you want to measure, this will suffice. But if you wish to measure engagement, a better tactic would be to employ tracking at the action/controller level instead of session level. A combination of both is required to understand what users like and what they like not. Your purpose for tracking should decide what method/s you need to employ.
- Use a widely-adopted solution: [Google Analytics](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=google+analytics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=p1SyVf6zE7TG8AfY66voBA).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the hints though I need to consider "guest" users too which do not have a session. I was also thinking about tracking via pageId->IP-Address mapping but as you said, that'd miss a lot of users.

I actually need to show the page views on each page so GA is not an option here.

How do the "big ones" handle this, I am curious?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the big ones handle this. I'd guess it's just a mix of all the listed techniques. But I found off a quick search that: you can find url-wise analytics from GA and can share specific bits publicly (hence add them on your site). Couldn't find a thorough tutorial though, and I've little idea of GA so I may be wrong.